# fadeOut div's opacity and fadeIn other

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

I want to make a div's opacity fadeout when I click on a "li" and then fade in another div..
This works on the first one, but the second one won't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#home").click(function(){
$(".kleur").animate({opacity:0},"slow");
$("#green").animate({opacity:1},"slow");
});
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).(function(){
$("#wiezijnwij").click(function(){
$(".kleur").animate({opacity:0},"slow");
$("#red").animate({opacity:1},"slow");
});
});
</script>
```

I am not the best in jquery, so I think it just might be something stupid I didn't see

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cTQJv/)

I don't know but somehow it doesn't work on jsfiddle (first time I used it)

Comment: Don't put events on your LI, put them on the A-tags.

Comment: It doesn't work on jsFiddle because your divs are positioned over the links and stopping the click event.

Comment: @j08691 ooh sorry, but you can see the code, so it doesn't matter that much right?

Comment: Well if you fix the positioning issue and the improperly closed divs in your example, it seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/cTQJv/4/

Comment: @OussamaDooby They're saying after you fix that, it works just as we understand you're wanting it to.

Comment: @j08691 http://jsfiddle.net/cTQJv/5/

Comment: @WillemEllis No the thing is I wanted to change a whole background with it.

But nvm I got it! http://jsfiddle.net/cTQJv/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't terminate your `div` tags. So it thinks the `#red` div is inside the `#green` div. This should work with the same javascript.

```
<ul>
    <li id="home"><a href="#start">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li id="wiezijnwij"><a href="#description">Wie zijn wij</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="kleur" id="green"></div>
<div class="kleur" id="red"></div>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/cTQJv/8/

Comment: @OussamaDooby Lol I saw that you figured it out after I posted this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [**working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uGxVk/)

This happened because of positioning and inline close tag of the `div`s.

```
<div class="kleur" id="green"></div>
<div class="kleur" id="red"></div>
```

so remove the below css:

```
#green, #red {
top:0;
left:0;
}
```

Better have some external styles because it is confusing

```
#green {
    background:#98bf21;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position: absolute; 
    opacity: 0;
}
#red {
    background:#606060;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position: absolute;       
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: No the positioning had nothing to do with it... It was only in the fiddle

The problem was that the div's werent closed right, the ID had to be in the "a" tag and some other things.

Look http://jsfiddle.net/cTQJv/5/

Here I moved the divs under the li's and it still didnt work

Comment: We had already discussed this. Although this was causing the fiddle to behave incorrectly, it was not the issue he was referring to.

Comment: @WillemEllis without knowing about the close tag issue, I made a working fiddle (**I missed to mentioned about the close tags**). check his previous fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cTQJv/10/ with correct closing tag.  Along with that OP has to remove `top:0;
left:0;`  then it works:) http://jsfiddle.net/cTQJv/11/

Comment: @user1671639 Understood. I was just saying he had hinted at the fact that this problem was only in the fiddle and not in his actual code. It seemed to me to be a point that he had simply overlooked when creating the fiddle itself.

Comment: @WillemEllis No problem :) I just wanted to share.